How to prevent simultaneous reproduction logic between two threads?
I have created a Fish class that simulates a fish that reproduces in a Java program. Each fish must breed by meeting another random fish. The problem is that two fish find each other as a pair and create two children at the same time. This process of reproduction is repeated several times at the same time.
I am keeping fish in Aquarium class. After the fish is born, after it reaches the breeding age (i.e. should start at 4 years old), it should find a random mate from the Aquarium class. In the code I wrote, a fish wants to find a mate and reproduce, and at this moment, that fish also reproduces by choosing the first fish from the Aquarium class. Two fishes will be born in one place in the sea. Actually, one fish should be born.
I can't figure out how to solve this problem. The real problem is in the method of reproduction. Where and how to write it. Please suggest me optimal solutions.
I have a Fish class:
package lesson.uz;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Random;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Fish extends Thread {

    private long id;
    private Gender gender;
    private Integer lifespan;
    private String fishName;
    private Integer age = 0;
    private static Long counter = 1L;

    public Fish(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.lifespan = new Random().nextInt(11)+40;
        this.fishName = "Fish"+ counter++;
        this.id = Math.abs(new Random().nextLong() * System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(fishName + " created. "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                reproduce();
                age++;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

    public void reproduce() {
        Fish randomFish = getRandomFish();
        long count = Aquarium.raddom.stream().filter(id -> randomFish.getId() == id || this.getId() == id).count();

        if (count == 0 && this.age >= 4 && randomFish.getAge() >= 4 && this.getGender() != randomFish.getGender()) {

            Aquarium.raddom.add(this.id);
            Aquarium.raddom.add(randomFish.id);

            System.out.println(this.fishName + " and " + randomFish.getFishName() + " meet.\n");
            Fish babyFish = createFish();
            Aquarium.fishList.add(babyFish);
            Aquarium.raddom.remove(this.id);
            Aquarium.raddom.remove(randomFish.id);
        }
    }

    public static Fish createFish() {
        Fish newFish = new Fish(Math.random() > 0.5 ? Gender.MALE : Gender.FEMALE);
        newFish.start();
        return newFish;
    }

    public Fish getRandomFish() {
        int randomNum = 0;
        Fish currenFish = null;
        while (true) {
            randomNum = new Random().nextInt(Aquarium.fishList.size());
            currenFish = Aquarium.fishList.get(randomNum);

            if (this != currenFish) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return currenFish;
    }
}

I have a Aquarium class:
package lesson.uz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Aquarium extends Thread {

    public static List<Fish> fishList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<Long> raddom = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
    }
}

and Main class:
package lesson.uz;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aquarium aquarium = new Aquarium();
        aquarium.start();
        init();
    }

    public static void init() {
        Fish fish1 = new Fish(Gender.MALE);
        fish1.start();
        Aquarium.fishList.add(fish1);
        Fish fish2 = new Fish(Gender.FEMALE);
        fish2.start();
        Aquarium.fishList.add(fish2);
    }
}

Problem (Problem):
Fish A and Fish B choose each other as a mate.
At the same time, Fish B also selects Fish A and begins the process of reproduction in parallel.
As a result, two children are created at the same time.
How to solve this problem? How can you ensure that the reproduction process only happens once at a time?
public static List<Long> raddom = new ArrayList<>();

I tried to solve the problem by adding a raddom (in the sense of a maternity ward) list. My program is not finished yet, but it didn't help. Please suggest me optimal solutions.

this.getGender() != randomFish.getGender()  …Unless your fish are seahorses, I’m pretty sure that should be this.getGender() == Gender.FEMALE.

What is ”raddom”?

@Basil Bourque "Raddom" is a word in Uzbek that means "maternity hospital" or "a place where babies are born." It's used here to represent a temporary list or space where fish couples are tracked during reproduction.

@VGR Thank u. I solved this issue based on your idea. That is, from the side of the female fish, I selected a male fish and bred it. For this, inside Aquarium, I have public static CopyOnWriteArrayList adultMaleFishList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); I opened a list and kept male fish older than 4 years old. The female fish randomly takes a fish from the adultMaleFishList and reproduces, and the male fish is added back to the list. So I managed to solve the problem by improving the idea you gave.

High Level
I would remove the reproduce method from the Fish class and place it in the Aquarium class. When a fish is old enough to reproduce it will call the Aquarium reproduce method. The Aquarium will add the Fish to the list, if there are at least two fish in the list, remove them, and create a new fish. (There may be a better way to implement this, but it will work.)
I also recommend changing new ArrayList<>(); to Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()).

If this is a real problem and not just a training exercise, you can't have one fish per thread... Number of fishes grows exponentially and you will run out of threads fast.
Usually people have single threaded games (this looks like a little game to me):
public class Fish {
    int age;
    @Getter
    GENDER gender;
    boolean pregnant;

    enum GENDER {
        MALE,
        FEMALE
    }

    public boolean isLookingForPartner() {
        return !isDead() && age >= 2 && !pregnant;
    }

    public void getPregnant() {
        if (gender == GENDER.FEMALE) {
            pregnant = true;
        }
    }

    public Fish giveBirth() {
        if (pregnant) {
            pregnant = false;
            //generate random gender
            GENDER randomGender = Math.random() < 0.5 ? GENDER.MALE : GENDER.FEMALE;
            System.out.println("NEW BABY FISH");
            return new Fish(0, randomGender, false);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public boolean isDead() {
        return age >= 10;
    }

    public void tick() {
        age++;
    }

}

public class Container {
    private final List<Fish> fishList;

    public Container(List<Fish> fishList) {
        this.fishList = fishList;
    }

    public void addFish(Fish fish) {
        fishList.add(fish);
    }

    public void tick() {
        fishList.removeIf(Fish::isDead);

        List<Fish> babies = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Fish fish : fishList) {
            fish.tick();
            Fish baby = fish.giveBirth();
            if (baby != null) {
                babies.add(baby);
            }
        }

        fishList.addAll(babies);

        List<Fish> maleFish = fishList.stream().filter(it -> it.getGender() == Fish.GENDER.MALE).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Fish> femaleFish = fishList.stream().filter(it -> it.getGender() == Fish.GENDER.FEMALE).collect(Collectors.toList());

        int femaleCounter = 0;

        for (Fish male : maleFish) {
            if (!male.isLookingForPartner()) {
                continue;
            }

            Fish female = null;
            while (female == null || !female.isLookingForPartner()) {
                if (femaleCounter == femaleFish.size()) {
                    return;
                }
                female = femaleFish.get(femaleCounter);
                femaleCounter++;
            }

            female.getPregnant();
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Container container = new Container(new ArrayList<>());
        container.addFish(new Fish(0, Fish.GENDER.FEMALE, false));
        container.addFish(new Fish(0, Fish.GENDER.MALE, false));
        int iteration = 0;
        while (true) {
            container.tick();
            Thread.sleep(300);
            iteration++;
            System.out.printf("Iteration {}", iteration);
        }
    }

}


At the company where I want to work, this problem is always given during the interview process. The purpose of this question is to evaluate the candidate's understanding of Threads, multithreading, and how to handle issues that arise in multithreading environments. Specifically, it assesses their knowledge of concepts like synchronized, volatile, and how they use these to resolve such problems.

@TuychiSharipov in this case introduce a fish state "pregnant true/false", make it volatile and synchronize a method that updates this state.

Thank you all. I managed to solve this problem. There have been a few changes to my code. Let me tell you the idea that I used to solve my problem:
"The first two fish, male and female, appear. Fish can reproduce from the age of 4. When the male fish is 4 years old, I add it to the adultMaleFishList. When a female fish turns 4 years old, she starts looking for a mate randomly from the adultMaleFishList. After finding a mate, we delete the male fish from the adultMaleFishList. And these two fish will mate and give birth to a new babyFish and after that these fish will rest for 3 years. After 3 years, we will add the male fish to the adultMaleFishList. The female fish again starts looking for a mate in the adultMaleFishList, and so on. When the age of the fish is equal to the age of death, the fish dies and we delete it from the fishList. When the fishList runs out of fish, the program stops. This is how the pretend I used works".
An example of my program code:
Main class:
package lesson.uz;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fish fish1 = new Fish(Gender.MALE);
        fish1.start();
        Aquarium.fishList.add(fish1);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1_00);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Fish fish2 = new Fish(Gender.FEMALE);
        fish2.start();
        Aquarium.fishList.add(fish2);

        Information.start();
    }

}

Fish class:
package lesson.uz;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Random;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Fish extends Thread {

    private Gender gender;
    private Integer lifespan;
    private String fishName;
    private Integer age = 0;
    private boolean isAddedToList;
    private Integer spawnInterval;

    public Fish(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.lifespan = new Random().nextInt(6) + 10;
        this.isAddedToList = false;
        this.spawnInterval = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                if(this.age >= this.lifespan){
                    if(this.gender == Gender.MALE){
                        Aquarium.adultMaleFishList.remove(this);
                        Aquarium.fishList.remove(this);
                        Information.maleFish.decrementAndGet();
                    }else{
                        Aquarium.fishList.remove(this);
                        Information.femaleFish.decrementAndGet();
                    }
                    Information.diedFish.incrementAndGet();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

                if(spawnInterval == 0 || spawnInterval == 1 || spawnInterval == 2 || spawnInterval == 3) {
                    if(spawnInterval == 3){
                        if(gender == Gender.MALE){
                            Aquarium.adultMaleFishList.add(this);
                        }
                        spawnInterval = -1;
                    }else {
                        spawnInterval++;
                    }
                }

                if(gender == Gender.FEMALE && age>=4 && spawnInterval==-1){
                    reproduce();
                }

                if(!isAddedToList && gender == Gender.MALE && age>=4){
                    Aquarium.adultMaleFishList.add(this);
                    isAddedToList = true;
                }

                age++;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static Fish createFish() {
        Fish newFish = new Fish(Math.random() > 0.5 ? Gender.MALE : Gender.FEMALE);
        newFish.start();
        if (newFish.getGender() == Gender.MALE) {
            Information.maleFish.incrementAndGet();
        }else {
            Information.femaleFish.incrementAndGet();
        }
        return newFish;
    }

    public void reproduce() {
        Fish randomFish = Aquarium.getRandomMaleFish();

        if(randomFish == null){
            return;
        }

        this.spawnInterval = 0;
        Fish babyFish = createFish();
        Aquarium.fishList.add(babyFish);
    }
}

Aquarium class:
package lesson.uz;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class Aquarium {

    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Fish> fishList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Fish> adultMaleFishList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public static synchronized Fish getRandomMaleFish() {
        if(adultMaleFishList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        Fish selectedFish = adultMaleFishList.get(new Random().nextInt(adultMaleFishList.size()));

        selectedFish.setSpawnInterval(0);
        adultMaleFishList.remove(selectedFish);
        return selectedFish;
    }
}

Information class:
package lesson.uz;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Information {

    public static AtomicInteger allFish = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static AtomicInteger maleFish = new AtomicInteger(1);
    public static AtomicInteger femaleFish = new AtomicInteger(1);
    public static AtomicInteger diedFish = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void start() {
        System.out.println("\n=====================     Start     =====================\n");

        while (true) {

            allFish.set(Aquarium.fishList.size());

            System.out.println("All fish: " + allFish+
                    "\nMale fish: " + maleFish +
                    "\nFemale fish: " + femaleFish +
                    "\nDied fish: " + diedFish +"\n");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            if(allFish.get() == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("=====================     Finish     =====================");
    }
}

Gender enum:
package lesson.uz;

public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE
}

It's true that my code is not pretty. My code may not be beautifully written based on SOLID, OOP principles. Because I am still new to programming. Thanks to everyone who helped me solve this problem.

The primary thing i see is you have to synchronize the reproduction so the same fish cannot be part of two reproduction processes.
You could have a checkForReproduction method in the aquarium class itself which is synchronized so limit access to a single thread.
public synchronized void checkForReproduction(Fish fish) {
    if (!fish.canReproduce()) return;

    for (Fish otherFish : fishes) {
        if (otherFish != fish && otherFish.canReproduce() &&
            !otherFish.getGender().equals(fish.getGender())) {

            // Reproduction 
            String babyName = "BabyFish" + (fishes.size() + 1);
            String babyGender = random.nextBoolean() ? "Male" : "Female";
            Fish babyFish = new Fish(babyName, babyGender, this);
            System.out.println("new baby fish with name: " + babyName + ", gender: " + babyGender);

            addFish(babyFish);
            break;
        }
    }
}

But making the whole method synchronized would restrict reproduction for one pair of fish at a time. To improve this we could have fish level synchronization.
public void checkForReproduction(Fish fish) {
    if (!fish.canReproduce()) return;

    Fish partner = findPartner(fish);
    if (partner != null) {
        synchronized (fish) {
            synchronized (partner) {
                if (fish.canReproduce() && partner.canReproduce()) {
                    reproduce(fish, partner);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

